# how to fetch telegram channels subscribers count from source code

Tags: java, android, telegram

I want to get a channel subscribers count without joining to that channel. 
I don't want to use a bot for it. 
below code which I used, returned zero for count.

This is a part of my code:

```
TLRPC.Chat chat = MessagesController.getInstance(currentAccount).getChat(chat id);
int count = chat.participants_count;
```

Comment: What logs shows?

Comment: shows the 0 in log

Comment: Add all logs. There suppose to be a response from telegram. Need to see it